# How to handle "Facebook style" slide in / fly in / side navigation menu in iOS7?

Tags: navigation, ios

With the recent announcement of iOS 7 a new system wide slide from left edge to right gesture to go back has been introduced. This appears to affect applications that use navigation controllers.  When a new view is pushed onto the navigation controller stack this gesture is activated.  A probable conflict has arisen with the "Facebook" style slide in navigation menu.

We had just completed a conversion from tabs to this side menu navigation pattern. There were advantages to it for simplifying navigation in complex applications.  But it appears that this is no longer possible.

They question is:

**What other navigation patterns can successfully support complex applications with multiple main level features?  Are we stuck with the inferior tab navigation or adding some item to a bottom toolbar to call that nav menu and eat up more valuable real estate on an already small screen?**

Thanks for your feedback.  I have a feeling this will be a problem that will affect many app designers with the transition to iOS 7.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't even aware you could swipe in the menu in the Facebook app... I guess we'll jut have to push the button then?

Comment: Wait there's no way you can disable swipe to go back feature in your app?

Comment: @nashmaniac Unfortunately, there is very little documentation on this new gesture.  It appears as if it is system wide and always on.  But I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to disable to edge-pan pop-gesture recognizer as provided in the  navigation controller. It is the default behavior, so removing it will divert from this platform-specific design pattern.

There actually is a new edge-pan gesture recognizer in iOS7 that you can attach to your current drawer implementation, making your implementation feel as native as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The "system wide slide from left edge to right gesture" is specific to applications, it's not doing anything in the calculator or other app

You can still have the FB navigation patterns, after all this is exactly how the Mail app is working

Comment: It appears as if this gesture is only enabled when a view is pushed onto the stack of a navigation controller.  Thus in simple applications, like calculator, this gesture is not enabled.  I've edited my question to include this point.

Comment: ok I see it.. looks like it only works when there is a "Back" button

Comment: Yeah there's next to no documentation with Apple talking about this change.  I just saw it on the WWDC keynote and from personal experience.  It's easy to miss.